# AC Goodman unit not powering on

Tags: hvac

Is getting hot and I tried to power on my AC unit, it only blows warm air and no sound from unit outside, fan is not moving, no noise.

- Checked indoor fuses were on and reset them
- Checked outdoor fuse was on and reset it
- Just changed the capacitor and turn AC on and nothing same situation
- tested old and new capacitor with meter looks good
- tested current in contactor and is fine to 240v

[image]

[Capacitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd7CM.jpg)

[Contactor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwwpk.jpg)

When I push the middle part of contactor, AC starts should I replace the contactor?

Comment: Can you post a wiring diagram for your AC unit?

Comment: Do you get 24VAC at the coil terminals of the contactor when the thermostat calls for cooling?

Comment: I don't get 24v I connected my meter to blue and yellow and nothing :(

Comment: Does jumpering R to Y at the thermostat base (with the thermostat removed) cause the A/C compressor to come on?

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/c0WJPat this is the current setup

Comment: Yeah -- that doesn't tell me anything, the jumper will tell me if the problem's the t-stat or the wire in the wall though.  I take it that prior 24V measurement was at the compressor-contactor end of things?

Comment: Will try tomorrow morning, yes the 24v measurement was at the compressor contactor

Comment: I did some testing. I currently have 2 t-stat: 1st floor: Nest, 2nd floor HoneyWell. Nest is throwing an error: e73 and claims there is no power in RC. I measure the power in t-stat and nothing between red cable and yellow/green/white. I'm kind of confused now. What is the typical connection from t-stat to Goodman AC unit, in t-stat I see 5 cables: (R, W, Y, G, B), outside in Goodman just 2 (contactor), is there supposed to be something in the middle, that I don't know of?

Comment: The thermostat cable normally goes to the indoor unit (air handler) with a second cable from the air handler to the compressor contactor.  Can you post a photo of the wiring at the air-handler?  Also, is there 24VAC from red to *blue* at the thermostat?